# intl date format is not formatting data as expected nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this format options

```
const dateTimeFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("default", {
  year: "numeric",
  month: "numeric",
  day: "numeric",
});
```

when I do `dateTimeFormat.format(new Date())` it return `3.9.2021` instead of `3/9/2021` as it is formatted in the docs

how can I fix this and why is this happening

Comment: well, what locale are you in?

Comment: @bravo locale is israel

Comment: also, your result should be (and is) a TIME not a DATE

Comment: How are you getting `3.9.2021` from Time format?

Comment: israel is not a locale ... what is your locale

Comment: @Bravo your right updated my question

Comment: hate to tell you this, but `d.m.yyyy` IS how dates are represented in **your** locale

Comment: if you want dd/mm/yyyy - use a locale that uses that date format, e.g. `"en-GB"` - p.s. your "locale" is `"he-IL"` - in case you are asked again

Comment: en-GB return 03/09 and I want 3/9

Comment: then just use `"en"`

Comment: @Bravo I see Ty man